# ASP.NETC# error while importing data from excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, dynamics-crm

i created web application using c# to import excel file into Microsoft Dynamics CRM. I used Fileupload to import the excel file.

Here is the code snippet:

Import Button:

```
if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
    {
        string FilePath = Path.GetFileName(this.FileUpload1.FileName);
        string FileName = Server.MapPath(Path.GetFileName(FilePath));
        string Extension = Path.GetExtension(this.FileUpload1.FileName);
        DataTable dt = ImportData(FileName, Extension);
```

And this is the ImportData code:

```
private DataTable ImportData(string Filepath, string Extension)
{
    string connString = "";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    switch (Extension)
    {
        case ".xls":
            connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx":
            connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
    }

    connString = string.Format(connString, Filepath, 1);

    try
    {
        OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        OleDbCommand excelCmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        excelCmd.Connection = excelConn;

        excelConn.Open();
        DataTable dtexcelschema;
        dtexcelschema = excelConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string SheetName = dtexcelschema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(); **The Error Come from this line**
        excelConn.Close();

        excelConn.Open();
        excelCmd.CommandText = "Select * from [" + SheetName + "]";
        oda.SelectCommand = excelCmd;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        excelConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Label1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    return dt;
}
```

When i tried to import excel to CRM. I got this message : "There is no row at position 0."

I dont know what happen here. Actually before i create web application, i created windows application using this code, and succes to import data. But when i copy this code into web application, i got that message.

EDITED

This is connection string inside web config:

```
<add name ="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"/>
<add name ="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1}'"/>
```

Comment: Are you saving the file after upload on server somewhere?

Comment: Nope, i just importing excel data into ms dynamics crm. And this code run well on windows application

Comment: what are you getting in the `Filepath` and do you have excel at same path with data?

Comment: hii, i edited my question, you can see what inside filepath is datasources. The data sources i get from the "Import Button"

Comment: You need to save the PostedFile first, only after that it's available to you. It's only existing in the stream / memory, not on the disk.Take a look at the actual file on the server.

Comment: @Leon: hii leon, can you show me the code snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This:

```
string Filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string Folderpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"];

        string Filepath = Server.MapPath(Folderpath + Filename);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Filepath);

        DataTable dt = ImportData(Filepath, Extension);
```